# Docker: how to see output/error of CMD [ "python", "./some_python.py" ]

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose for multi-container setup for my project. For that I need some data in my mongodb image and I have created a python file for same. Now in the build process, I am only getting below message in the console and not any other stdout/sterr messages.

```
Step 12 : CMD python ./import_testdata.py
 ---> Running in 352b86106f68
 ---> fe091f22c2db
```

I have tried below options in my dockerfile

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "python import_testdata.py > server.log 2>&1"]
CMD [ "python", "./import_testdata.py" ]
```

But I am not getting any success and also I couldn't see any error/output messages

See my Dockerfile at https://gist.github.com/dharmjit/a48ce2b6684b5a3f69a2056abca0b70b

Comment: show your Dockerfile

Comment: @user2915097 in below response I got to know I cant run two CMD. so i need to install python and other relevant packages in the particular image.  Is there another way

Comment: you can use an image containing Python, such as elyase/staticpython

Comment: link is not working, please put the docker file code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker Reference states: "There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect."
(https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Why don't you perform your actions with a RUN instruction?

Comment: or he can put these two CMD in a bash file and run that file!